# .htaccess Pretty URL rewrite like folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite one of my urls to pretty urls but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I've tried far.

My folder layout

```
-index.php
-.htaccess
-/product
    -category.php
    -index.php
    -product.php
```

my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category_id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

i'm tring to turn this url

```
http://example.com/product/category.php?category_id=1&category=car-and-buses
```

into this url

```
http://example.com/product/1/car-and-buses
```

everything what i tried so far gives me miss-configuration error or 401.. on my browser

Comment: Is your .htaccess inside `product` directory by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you try to turn

```
http://example.com/product/1/car-and-buses
```

into this so you can fetch the parameters in your category.php with $_GET['category_id']

```
http://example.com/product/category.php?category_id=1&category=car-and-buses
```

Try this and place the .htaccess file in your root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On      
  RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*) /product/category.php?category_id=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT!**

Try this since the above solution doesn't work for you. This should rewrite all request to your index.php. This is not a solution to your question but try this to make sure there isn't any other problem whit your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you access the page direct? http://example.com/product/category.php?category_id=1&category=car-and-buses

Comment: Add a slash before product in the RewriteUrl, se my edited answer. If it still doesn't work try adding R to your flags [R,QSA,L] and se where you end up

Comment: i am using it on localhost should i try it on server??

Comment: Yes, you can try that but which URL did you come to when you added R to the flags? Is your .htaccess in the root? Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled now.
but still not worked
do you have any more suggestion to do this

Comment: Is your .htaccess in the root folder? Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Se my edited answer

Comment: the second answer is working but a little problem is we cant use another $2 with the code
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ product/category.php?category_id=$1&category=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`


this type of request url

`http://example.com/product/category.php?category_id=1/car&category=`

from this

`http://example.com/1/car`
please try to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97286/discussion-between-andy-and-divakarcool).